# How can I loop through a users status update schema?

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm working on a Facebook clone and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to loop through the Status update Schema. The way I have it set up now, it loops through the entire Schema and is displaying all status updates but I need it to where it only shows the status updates of whoever's profile I visit. Example: `/users/dagger` would only show status updates to whoever's username is Dagger. Here is the code I'm using.

```
<% status_list.forEach(function(status) { %> 
  <div class="status">
    <p><%= status.content %></p>
    <button class="like-btn">♡</button>
  </div>
<% }); %>
```

Here is my Status Schema

```
const statusSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  author: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

User Schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  username: String,
  password: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

and here is my form for creating status updates.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <div>
    <label for="content"></label>
    <textarea
      id="content"
      type="text"
      name="content"
      placeholder="What's On Your Mind?"
   ></textarea>
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="author"></label>
    <input
      id="author"
      type="text"
      name="author"
      value="<%= user.username %>"
      hidden
    />
   </div>
   <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```